# Клавиша тильды на MacOS(Hackintosh)

Tags: mac, macos

Добрый день! На работе пользуемся хакинтошами. Недавно сменил компьютер и появилась одна проблема. То ли переопределена, то ли я использую не ту раскладку, но в общем за место клавиши "тильда" у меня - ±. А по скольку постоянно пользуюсь консолью(а это самый простой способ попасть в домашней каталог), да и хоткей очень удобный висит на этой кнопке, то очень бы хотелось вернуть именно тильду. Не подскажите в какую сторону копать? Гугл ничем не помог. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Это нормально, на Mac-овской клавиатуре на месте, где у PC-клавиатуры ~, расположен ±, а тильда рядом с левым shift.

Answer (score 1):

не пользовался хакинтошем, но в макосе посоветовал бы сменить раскладку в настройки->язык и текст->источники ввода. там обычно для русских и английских клавиатур бывает несколько раскладок.

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Попробуй этот вариант (добавлены еще шоткаты по навигации из Win):

```
cd ~/Library
mkdir KeyBindings
cd KeyBindings


cat > DefaultKeyBinding.dict << EOF
{
/* Tilda &  Baktik*/
"§" = ("insertText:", "`"); 
"±" = ("insertText:", "~"); /* Tilda */

/* Remap Home / End keys to be correct */
"\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLine:"; /* Home */
"\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLine:"; /* End */
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Home */
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + End */
"^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:"; /* Ctrl + Home */
"^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocument:"; /* Ctrl + End */
"@\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:"; /* Command + Home */
"@\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocument:"; /* Command + End */
"^\UF702" = "moveWordLeft:"; /* Ctrl + Left */
"^\UF703" = "moveWordRight:"; /* Ctrl + Right */
"~\UF702" = "moveWordLeft:"; /* Option + Left */
"~\UF703" = "moveWordRight:"; /* Option + Right */
"^\UF72C" = "pageUp:"; /* Ctrl + Page Up */
"^\UF72D" = "pageDown:"; /* Ctrl + Page Down */
"$^\UF72C" = "pageUpAndModifySelection:"; /* Ctrl + Shift + Page Up */
"$^\UF72D" = "pageDownAndModifySelection:"; /* Ctrl + Shift + Page Down */
"$^\UF702" = "moveWordLeftAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + Left */
"$^\UF703" = "moveWordRightAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + Right */
"$^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + Home */
"$^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:"; /* Shift + Ctrl + End */
}
EOF
```

Источники:

1. https://toster.ru/q/266983
2. http://severe-programmer.com/manual/os-x-obrabotka-klavish-home-end-etc-kak-v-windows/

Comment: старайтесь писать развернутые ответы. Ответы - ссылки не приветствуются, лучше вынести ключевую информацию из ссылки в ответ, указав ссылку на источник.